# Xcode Using XIBs to move non-modally to view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I currently have my first app, which uses a storyboard. From the first view, I can be 8 model views deep before returning back to the start.

I think using XIBs (not storyboards) is better for my application. I would like to learn how to do all the views in code but all the books and tutorials treat code as a black plague. Hard to learn if no one teaches anymore.

My concern with my 8 deep modal string of views is that memory is consumed by each view and not released until I fall back to the start - releasing each one as I fall back.

My application is a state machine (so I want to simple move from one view to another), releasing all aspects of the view just being left. As I move from one state to the next, I release the current view as I move to the next one.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. You could create a custom container controller (which would exist for the life of the run), and switch out which controller is embedded in it. As long as you have nothing pointing to the one that you replace, it will be deallocated.

A simpler solution, but one I don't really like to use, is to replace the window's root view controller with the next controller you want to go to, which will also cause the replaced one to be deallocated.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think or know about the two options you stated.The other option I was thinking about was to have the main viewcontroller be the statemachine manager.  As a view retires and returns to the main it can bring back a state change variable which will tell main what the next view is to be made active.  That would reduce my memory usage to having only two views in memory at any one time.

Comment: @JHinkle, you could do that with a custom container controller -- it could be your state machine manager.